# FUSE-like virtualized network adapter?

Tags: networking, cross-platform, virtualization

[FUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) enables you to write stuff easily like SQL database, [GMail](http://richard.jones.name/google-hacks/gmail-filesystem/gmail-filesystem.html) or even [Wikipedia articles](http://wikipediafs.sourceforge.net/) as your local filesystem files. Is there something similar for networking world? [VTUN](http://vtun.sourceforge.net/) seems fine but works only in *nix OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenVPN (http://openvpn.net) installer for windows ships with TAP-Win32, which is the Windows port of the *nix TUN/TAP drivers.